# Avoid Eloquent model event from being triggered multiple/ infinite times using Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have the following code:

AppServiceProvider:

```
User::saved(function (User $user) {
    return $user->modifiedEvent();
});

User::deleted(function (User $user)   
    return $user->modifiedEvent();
});
```

In my  `User` model I have:

```
    public function modifiedEvent()
    {
        $stage = $this->isDirty('terms_and_conditions') 
             && $this->terms_and_conditions !== null ? 'completed' : 'incomplete';
        $this->stage_terms_and_conditions = $stage;
        return $this->save();
    }
```

The issue I have is that the `modifiedEvent` also modifies the model, which means we get an infinite loop!

Whats the best way to make sure that this event is not triggered multiple times due caused by the event it self.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to use the **'saving'** event so there is no need to call $this->save() at the end.